# Deriving a homeomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to come up with homeomorphisms between the following sets

$\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $\{(s,t):s>0\}$

$\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$

On the first, I am thinking that I let $f(x)=e^{x}$ then $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is a bijection. So $f$ is a continuous bijection and $f^{-1}$ is continuous. So I figure that I can somehow use the exponential to find a function of two variables that will work for the first. Am I on the right track and if so how can I use $e^{x}$ as a function of two variables?

Comment: You're on the right track for the first case. Just let $(s, t) \mapsto (e^s, t)$.

Comment: For the second, $(s,t)\to (2/\pi\arctan s,\;2/\pi\arctan t)$.

Comment: So the inverses would be $(s,t)\mapsto(ln(s),t) $ and $(s,t)\mapsto(2/\pi\tan s,2/\pi\tan t)$ right? So $2/\pi \arctan x$ a bijection?

Comment: The arctangent is a continuous bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $-\pi/2, \pi/2$.

Comment: excellent, I truly appreciate the input!